# Xamarin Forms navigation stack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

As far as I’ve seen, if the host native Activity is recreated, the Xamarin Forms Pages are recreated.
This can be easily tested if I enable “Don’t keep activities” on the device.
I expected the NavigationPage to retain the back stack with the Xamarin Forms Pages.

How can I retain the back stack?
Do I have to implement my own NavigationPage? 
What options do I have with current version of Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 2):

if you remember [push and pop operation in stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) then this image will give you all you need

[image: visual representation of page navigation in xamarin forms]

Answer (score 1):

Andrei,

Make the root view controller your NavigationPage you can push as many ContentPage(s) as you would like. The Navigation Page is keeping the stack of views being pushed automatically and then you can Pop them to your rootview ContentPage or previous ContentPage(s)...

```cs
var mainNav = new NavigationPage(new BoxedView());
```

then to push:

```cs
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
    Navigation.PushAsync(CONTENT_PAGE_OBJECT, false));
```

to pop:

```cs
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Navigation.PopAsync(true));
```

Comment: when switching away from the app and then switching back, what happens if all pages instances get destroyed (suppose because of low memory)? creating and pushing ALL Xamarin Forms Page instances at once when the native host view is recreated might not look good. The problem with Xamarin Forms is that I can't recreate the navigation stack based on page types, it only works with instances. As a solution, I might be able to override navigating back and insert page based on saved backstack; I was looking to see if someone has already implemented this right

Comment: I see, so you are worried about memory footprint.. 

How about if you create your own Navigation Controller where you construct the class based on the page you want to display.. the bad thing about this is that you will need to keep retain count of the stack and destroy the page objects once you pop the views...

Intriguing combination... Let us know if you are able to come up with something.. good luck..

Comment: No, it's not about memory footprint. As I mentioned, the navigation backstack in Xamarin Forms works with instances of Pages, see INavigation interface. So, when recreating the backstack you have to create all Pages and push them back. But each page has its own view-model, so this is created too. View-models can call different services.  The backstack should not work with instances, unless Xamarin Forms really supports recreating the backstack by itself, taking care of Page creation only when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Here you can manage the Navigation stack**

```
// Adding pages to Navigation stack

Xamarin.Forms.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
Xamarin.Forms.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(), false));
Xamarin.Forms.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3(), false));

// Removing pages from Navigation stack

var page3 = Xamarin.Forms.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(false));
var page2 = Xamarin.Forms.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(false));
var page1 = Xamarin.Forms.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(false));
```